# Segmentation Fault occurring while assigning Daemon Threads for a Helper Function

Tags: python

I am doing data analysis on a dataset which features 55 million rows. Specifically, I am calculating the total distance between two points on Earth, which is a sphere, given their coordinates in terms of their latitudes and longitudes. The formula I'm using to calculate this distance is the haversine formula. I am using the numpy python library to perform the haversine calculation on each set of points.

Considering the size of my dataset, it would be highly beneficial to fully utilize all 4 threads that my processor possesses. So, I'm using the following code snippet to distribute slices of my Pandas dataframe (the data structure I'm using the store the latitude and longitude values of the two points in question) and assign each thread to a helper function which processes each slice:

```
CHUNK_AMOUNT = 4  #set this value to the number of threads you can afford to use
ind = 0 #start index of each slice, and set is the pandas dataframe
for i in range(CHUNK_AMOUNT):
    chunk = set[ind:int((i+1)*(set.shape[0]/CHUNK_AMOUNT))]
    t = threading.Thread(target=calculate_abs_displacement, args=(chunk, i))
    #calculate_abs_displacement is the implementation of the haversine distance  
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    ind = int((i+1)*(set.shape[0]/CHUNK_AMOUNT))
```

However, when I run my code, I get the following error: Segmentation fault (core dumped). For the sake of reference, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a local machine (not a VM) with a quad-core Intel Core i5-2400 CPU.

Just for the sake of reference, when I run the "top" command in terminal, I find that only one core is at 100% while the rest of the cores are at 0% utilization. Then, after the error message shows up in console, all CPU cores are at 0% usage. What is the cause of this erratic behavior?

Comment: What happens if you use user threads instead of daemons?

Comment: so, your code does not show any real relation to pandas. Your code example is numpy as you mentioned above. However, to leverage multiple cores within pandas, you might want to take a look at the `dask`library

Comment: @MSeifert: I get the same result when I set t.setDaemon(False).
Quickbeam: I'll look at dask and get back to you if I have any doubts.